# Derivation from complex simultaneous equations (transmission of a resonator)

Tags: proof-verification, systems-of-equations, physics

> I am trying to verify a derivation presented in a [journal article](https://www.hajim.rochester.edu/optics/sites/boyd/assets/pdf/publications/Heebner_JQE_04.pdf), where the authors derive an expression for the transmission of a lossy fiber ring resonator.
>
> They start with the equations:
>
> $$\begin{cases}
> E_{2}=rE_{1}+itE_{3} & \text{(i)}\\
> E_{4}=rE_{3}+itE_{1} & \text{(ii)}\\
> E_{3}=\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)E_{4} & \text{(iii)}\\
> r^{2}+t^{2}=1 & \text{(iv)}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> and arrive at this solution:
>
> $$\frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}=\exp\left[i\left(\pi+\varphi\right)\right]\frac{\tau-\exp\left(-i\varphi\right)}{1-r\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)} \tag{1}$$

I was not able to reach the same solution. I started by substituting (iii) into (ii) to obtain:

$$E_{3}=it\left[\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}-r}\right]E_{1}.$$

Putting this into (i) and solving for the desired ratio:

$$\frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}=\frac{\frac{\exp\left(-i\varphi\right)}{\tau}r-r^{2}-t^{2}}{\frac{\exp\left(-i\varphi\right)}{\tau}-r}=\frac{r-\tau\left[r^{2}-t^{2}\right]\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}{1-\tau r\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}.$$

From (iv) we can use the relation $r^{2}-t^{2}=2r^{2}-1$ to write:

$$\frac{r-2\tau r^{2}\exp\left(i\varphi\right)-\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}{1-r\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}.$$

However, this is not the correct answer. Using Euler's formula I believe we can rewrite the author's solution (Eqn. 1) as:

$$\frac{E_{2}}{E_{1}}=\frac{r-\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}{1-r\tau\exp\left(i\varphi\right)}.$$

Therefore my formula has an extra "$-2\tau r^{2}\exp\left(i\varphi\right)$" term in it.

So, is there a mistake in my derivation? Or is there a mistake in the article?

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** There is a typo in the paper with their Eqn. (3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sign issue, in the last step of your second equation. You have transformed $-r^2-t^2$ into $-(r^2-t^2)$ instead of $-(r^2+t^2)=-1$. Fixing this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used the equations as you wrote them.

Using $\text{(i)}$, I eliminated $E_3$; then, using $\text{(ii)}$, I eliminated $E_4$. Now, in $\text{(iii)}$ I set $E_2=x E_1$ and solved for $x$. This leads, using $\text{(iv)}$ to
$$x=\frac{E_2}{E_1}=\frac 1 r\left(1+\frac{r^2-1}{1-r \,\tau \, e^{i \varphi }} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. This is probably a better approach. Though, as Andrei pointed out, my problem was really an error with the sign.